# How to scroll only half of screen but be able to scroll anywhere?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I would like to make a website using react where only half of the screen scrolls, while the other screen stays fixed. This, on its own, is easy. However, I wanted to make it so that even if the user scrolls the scroll wheel on the fixed section, the scrolling section still scrolls down, and I have not been able to accomplish this.

So far, I just have a basic react setup, like so:

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="App">
      <FixedSection />
      <ScrollingSection />
    </div>
  };
}
```

FixedSection.js and ScrollingSection.js are just containers

FixedSection.css

```
.fixed-section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh; 
  }
```

ScrollingSection.css

```
.scrolling-section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

I have tried forwarding the scroll event to ScrollingSection from App using a ref, but it did not work. How would I go about achieving this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should try using create referance,
below code will helpful to  scroll wheel on the fixed section

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import FixedSection from './FixedSection';
import ScrollingSection from './ScrollingSection';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollingSectionRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleFixedSectionScroll = (e) => {
    // Forward the scroll event to the scrolling section
    this.scrollingSectionRef.current.scrollTop += e.deltaY;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <FixedSection onScroll={this.handleFixedSectionScroll} />
        <ScrollingSection ref={this.scrollingSectionRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

FixedSection.js

```
class FixedSection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fixed-section" onWheel={this.props.onScroll}>
        {/* Content of the fixed section */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FixedSection;
```

ScrollingSection.js

```
class ScrollingSection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="scrolling-section" ref={this.props.forwardRef}>
        {/* Content of the scrolling section */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <ScrollingSection forwardRef={ref} {...props} />
));
```

App.css

```
.fixed-section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .scrolling-section {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: 50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```